# How to make text hyperlink in AndEngine

Tags: andengine

Currently to open the link i am using button sprite. But now i want to link a text to website. Is there any way to do this in AndEngine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the link clickable and then go to url using intent.

```
      Text link = new Text(100, 100, this.mFont, "Link", this.getVertexBufferObjectManager()){

            @Override
    public boolean onAreaTouched(final TouchEvent pSceneTouchEvent, final float pTouchAreaLocalX, final float pTouchAreaLocalY) {
          switch(pSceneTouchEvent.getAction()) {
          case TouchEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
               Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
               i.setData(Uri.parse("http://www.google.com"));
               startActivity(i);
                  break;
          }
                        return true;
        }
            };
```